# How to use htmlentities with substring

Tags: php, substr

Can anyone explain why this substr is not working ? What am I missing ?

```
<?= substr(htmlentities($movie->movie_name) , 0 , 10) ?>
```

Comment: Give us an [mcve]. I have no idea what you mean with "not working"? What is your input?, what do you get as output? and what do you expect to get?

Comment: More info please? What is it doing?

Comment: I want tos show the first 10 characters of the result

Comment: Can you post an example of a title that doesn't work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably want to switch the order of these function calls, like this:

```
<?= htmlentities(substr($movie->movie_name, 0, 10)); ?>
```

`htmlentities` replaces special characters, such as `<` with `&lt;`. Where `<` was only one character for the `substr` function, `&lt;` took 4 spaces. Even worse, it could be cut of halfway, where you end up with `The big &l`.

Comment: Maybe this is the problem, but without more information this is pure speculation.

Comment: there was 1 character missing in your syntax, following was working :
<?= htmlentities(substr($model->model_name, 0, 20)) ?>

Answer (score 0):

you question is incomplete. it's not very thorough.
let me help.

- you use **utf-8** other than english language:

  ```
        you should use mb_substr instead to support multibyte characters in utf-8
  ```
- check if your **$movie->movie_name** is null or not string you can use

  > if($movie->movie_name !=null AND is_string($movie->movie_name)){
  >
  > echo substr(htmlentities($movie->movie_name) , 0 , 10);
  >
  > }else{
  >
  > echo 'no name!'
  >
  > }

Answer (score 0):

The correct code was :

```
<?= htmlentities(substr($movie->movie_name, 0, 10)) ?>
```